# Issue with Plotly() in Julia

Tags: julia, plotly, plots.jl

I am using Julia for potting.

I do the following:

```
img = load("/Users/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx-xxxx.png")

plot!(img)
plot!(x_coordinate_holder, y_coordinate_holder, color = :black, linewidth=0.4)
```

However when I add `plotly()` before the above code, it opens up a plot in the safari window, but it remains blank.  Any ideas to fix this?  The plot successfully shows up when I leave it with the default backend. My guess is that img is not supported with the plotly() backend. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Julia Plots docs [here](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/supported/), Only the `gr()`, `hdf5()` and `pyplot()` support the plotting of an image. Switching to one of those backends will resolve the issue.